# Stochastic Gradient Descent algorithm derivation

Tags: stochastic-processes, gradient-descent

In this question, I am not really sure how to approach this question as I am unsure of the concept of random sampling w.r.t to SGD

Consider the function

$f : B_1 → R$ with $f(x) = \left\lVert x \right\rVert_2^2$ and $B_1$ := {$x ∈ R_d : \left\lVert x \right\rVert_2 ≤ 1$}

as well as the optimization problem $\min_{x∈B1} f(x). $

Let $f_1, ... , f_n$ be independent copies of random functions that take the form $f_n(x) = dx_i^2$ with probability $ \frac 1d$ .

a) Set up a stochastic gradient descent algorithm to tackle the optimization problem.

$x_{i+1} = x_i -  ∂ ∇_xf(x_i,w_i) $

$∇_xf(x) = 2x$

$\implies 2x = \mathbf 0 $

$\implies x = \mathbf 0 $

$ x_{i+1} = x_i -  ∂ ∇_xf(2x_i,2dx_i) $

How do we show that $f_n$ meet the requirements to define a SGD?

How do you also determine the step size in the above algorithm and state the convergence guarantees for the SGD algorithm?

Comment: Could you try to edit this question to make it a bit clearer what you want to know?

Comment: Hi, I have edited it. I am not really sure how does SGD works in a theoretical sense with respect to sampling

Comment: I probably don't know the answer to your question, but for me it's difficult to work out why you have $x\implies 0$ and so on in the question, and then at the bottom you have two questions. Is the problem from a book or something? Perhaps you could give a source.

Comment: My apologies. ⟹0  was the working after finding the derivative of the objective function. There is no source as this was a given assignment

Comment: I don't think people can answer this kind of question where it says "Set up a stochastic gradient descent algorithm" very easily, could you try to improve the question even more so that people can understand what answer you need?